# Do I need to place a comma in this sentence? And is the word order correct?

Tags: word-order, commas

Do I need to place a comma in this sentence? And is the word order correct?

> Supporting guidance on 'Fair trading requirements' advises that discrimination in regard to the costs of the goods and services against owners wishing to obtain a written prescription is forbidden.

Answer (score -1):

Comma after discrimination and after prescription but note that this is still wordy and does not flow as a sentence.

Try
Supporting guidance on 'Fair trading requirements' advises that discrimination is forbidden  in regard to the costs of the goods and services, against those owners who wish to obtain a written prescription.